# Align flex items to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have aligned flex items using `justify-content: space-around;` In the example given below, I need to align the last item to the left. Please help.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, vitae venenatis est ultricies blandit. Aenean augue enim, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, vitae venenatis ela enim, dignissim non </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want it aligned to the left, or do you want it to line up with the left edge of the first item? The former might be possible, the latter is definitely not.

Comment: I want to line it up with the left edge of the first item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use margin instead of `justify-content: space-around;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 30%;
  margin:0 1.45%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, vitae venenatis est ultricies blandit. Aenean augue enim, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, </div>
  <div class="block">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum dui quam, vitae venenatis ela enim, dignissim non </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is there can be any number of blocks. If there are only 2 blocks, I need them center aligned.

Comment: You want to set left align to first item and center align to 2 item !!! It's can't be done by css ! May be javascript (JQuery)